# How to give background opacity on this navbar and align everything horizontally?

Tags: html, css, navbar, opacity

I've made the basic navbar but I'm having issues aligning everything and making the background opaque, so that the text and image come up brighter as shown in the [picture][1]. The [fiddle][2] is attached.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```css
.topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .topnav ul > li {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      color: white;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    /* dropdown menus hidden initially */
    .topnav ul > li > ul {
      display: none;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f76c38;
    }
    .topnav ul > li > ul > li {
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown > a").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: AvantGarde Demi;
  src: url(AvantGarde Demi.woff);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: AvantGarde;
  src: url(AvantGarde.woff);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ITC Avant Garde Gothic;
  src: url(ITC Avant Garde Gothic.woff);
}


/******************For Top Nav****************************/

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.topnav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
/* dropdown menus hidden initially */
.topnav ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f76c38;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul > li {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/******************For Top Nav****************************/



li.dropdown{
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png"></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><b>PROGRAMS</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><b>WORLD OF NORTHMAN</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#"><i>BE EXTRODINARY</i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>RISK &amp; REWARD</i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>BLOG</i></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i>OUR STORY</i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Please comment below, if you have some trouble with it. Or mark the **CHECK** mark if it is the solution :)

**UPDATE** 
Here is the output
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I need the world of northman to be on the same line as the logo and programs, how do I do that?

Comment: It is sir. Check it out if it is `Full page`. Click the `Full page`

Comment: @shortcut I have updated my answer, to see the exact result.

Comment: @shortcut you just have to change the place of your `<img>`. Less code, runs faster

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using `flexbox`. just update your CSS with following.

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

for updated fiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Display both elements as inline-block (or float:left) should do it:

```
.topnav > img, .topnav > nav {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

You will also need to adjust the height on the nav menu items (either with line-height or padding top/bottom, or both)

Comment: I'm putting this in but its not working as I think it should be could you update this in fiddle?